# How to create a sharing marketplace with wordpress for bicycles?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I want to create a marketplace for bicycles with wordpress. Users can register/login and sell their bicycle to other users. They also can create a pre-defined page for their bicycle...

Which wordpress plugins do i have to use or do I have to write my own plugin?

How would you create such a site?

Answer (score 1):

This question is way to broad. But yeah, everything is possible :P Look into e-commerce solutions since this is basically it - only it has to allow users to publish items.

Comment: Can you recommed one?

Comment: No, since that is not what WP answers is for. Read the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)